# Selecting value in datagrid using KeyUp event

Tags: c#, datagrid

i want to display the selected value in datagridview to textfields by using `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events

```
private void gridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.gridView.Rows[e.KeyCode];

            txtboxStudentNum.Text = row.Cells["ID_Number"].Value.ToString();
            txtboxName.Text = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
            comboCourse.SelectedItem = row.Cells["Course"].Value.ToString();
            EPCdisplay.Text = row.Cells["EPCNumber"].Value.ToString();
            txtboxSerialNum.Text = row.Cells["SerialNumber"].Value.ToString();
            txtboxModelNum.Text = row.Cells["ModelNumber"].Value.ToString();
            comboCategory.SelectedItem = row.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
            comboYrLevel.SelectedItem = row.Cells["Level"].Value.ToString();
            txtboxEquipDesc.Text = row.Cells["EquipDesc"].Value.ToString();
            comboSem.Text = row.Cells["Semester"].Value.ToString();


            AddDatabase get_image = new AddDatabase();
            get_image.ID = txtboxStudentNum.Text;
            get_image.getimage();


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think The Question Should be more precise? So, You Want to Show the selected Value of datagridview in a text field, is it so?

Comment: Yes all i want is to display the selected value of datagridview in text field every time i press the arrow key down

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to get the Value of **Selected Cell** then All you Need to is trigger the **DataGridView KeyDown Event** and write the code as

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            txtName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
            //do whatever you want to
        }
    }
```

and if you want to get the whole row and perform operations, you can do it as

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            txtID.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            //do whatever you want to
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code. Still it won't display the information on textboxes every time i press the arrow key down.

Comment: bro, it is not being triggered on key down press, rather it is being triggered on the stroke of Enter, if you want to do so on Key Down or Up you should change the **if statement** like this,  `if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Down)` or `if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Up)`